# Sort Articles by CaseAssociationCount issues SOSL

Tags: apex, visualforce, knowledge, sosl

Seems like Salesforce wont allow me to sort articles by caseassociation count as the parent. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

SOSL

```
FIND {*searchTerms*} RETURNING KnowledgeArticleVersion
    (Id, Title, ArticleType WHERE PublishStatus='online' AND Language = 'en_US' AND ArticleType IN ('Troubleshooting__kav', 'How_To__kav', 'FAQ__kav') **ORDER BY KnowledgeArticle.CaseAssociationCount DESC**)
    WITH DATA CATEGORY Topics__c AT *Category*
```

Error

```
'How_To__kav', 'FAQ__kav') ORDER BY KnowledgeArticle.CaseAssociationCount__r)
                                    ^
ERROR at Row:2:Column:161
Didn't understand relationship 'KnowledgeArticle' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Comment: I don't think you can traverse the relationship from KAV to KA...I just tried in Eclipse and it won't let you, it'll only do it for the KA.Id. The only other way I can think of is a wrapper class and a Map of KnowledgeArticles.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of how the class should be written?